# jQuery Default Validation Error appearing inside an input-box

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-validate

I've got this form. I've added the jQuery validation plugin on the form but whenever the validation error occurs it displays inside the input box. Here's the html code snippet.

I want the error to appear below the **email** box like it is happening for **password** box. The `<div id="emailInputGroup">` is causing the problem but if I remove it I loose the `input-group-addon`.

```
<div id="loginFormGroup" class="form-group">
  <label for="emailLabel" style="color:white"><strong>Email ID</strong></label>
  <div id="emailInputGroup" class="input-group">
    <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="abc" autofocus></input>
    <span class="input-group-addon">@abc.org</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="passwordLabel" style="color:white"><strong>Password</strong></label>
  <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="password" />
</div>
```

Here's the screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

I'm a beginner in web-development, so kindly bear with me if it appears to be a trivial question.
 Thank you.

This is the jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $.validator.addMethod("customValidator", function(value, element) {
    return /^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(value);
}, 'No special char2');

    $("#signIn").click( function(){
            $("#loginForm").valid(); //default
    });

    $("#loginForm").validate({
                rules: {
                        email: {
                                    required: true,
                                    minLength: 3,
                                    maxLength: 10,
                                    customValidator: true
                        },
                        password: {
                                    required: true,
                                    minLength: 4,
                                    maxLength: 32
                        }
                },
                message: {
                        email: {
                                    required:  "email can't be empty",
                                    minLength: "At least 3 email characters.",
                                    maxLength: "At most 10 email characters."

                        },
                        password: {
                                    required:  "password can't be empty",
                                    minLenght: "At least 4 password characters",
                                    maxLength: "At most 32 password characters"
                        }
                }
            });
});
```

I don't know if it is even syntactically correct or not.

Comment: any reasons for this being downvoted? :/

Comment: I have not down voted though, jquery validation appends error `<span>` just after input elements. But you can manipulate this by defining own jquery code error assignment inside the validate function. If you post your jquery validation function along with your question, I can help you...

Comment: Please mention the plugin used (with a link) and share your jQuery code used to initialize the plugin.

Comment: @ArunSharma It's **jQuery Validation Plugin** . I don't know if the plugin goes by any other name. It's by [jQueryValidationPlugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/)

Comment: @ArunSharma please see the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`errorPlacement`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#groups) to customize where you want to place your errors in jQuery Validate

```
$("#loginForm").validate({
   rules: {
      ..........
   },
   message: {
      ..........
   },
   errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
     // if the element is email, then append the error to its parent.
     // which means the error will be rendered below the span
     if (element.attr("name") == "email") {
       error.appendTo(element.closest('div'));
     } else {
       error.insertAfter(element); // this is the default behaviour
     }
   }
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adigas/1bszcvv2/1/)

Comment: It still is giving the error on the same row, but thanks I got the idea for how to do it.

Comment: @WhiteSword The fiddle is only for demonstration purposes. Styling and position you'll have to add it yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try removing the `</input>` and making the opening tag an inline tag? like:

```
<input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="abc" autofocus/>
```

does this work?

Comment: No. It doesn't.

Comment: You are right, your span is printing error that way. Because i see your password error and its fine. Try one more thing for me please. 
Try:     <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="abc" autofocus><span class="input-group-addon">@abc.org</span></input>

Comment: still the same problem.

Comment: Ok, remove customValidator: true

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work. Though thank you for answer. :  )

Comment: Answer has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Ye i got it the 3rd time i was wrong xD